# Hibernate and cassandra db connections and transactions

Tags: hibernate, cassandra

I have some idea of working with Hibernate and RDBMS .Can any friend provide some idea or any sample codes which explains how to work with Hibernate and Cassandra.

I need some sample code base on this respect.

Thanks in advance.

-Ankur.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra is not a relational database and does not work with Hibernate. Most Java users use [Hector](https://github.com/rantav/hector) with Cassandra.